# Shorten sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I do 3 queries to reorder the rows of my table

```
SELECT @i:=0;
UPDATE imagedata SET imagedata.rank = 0;
UPDATE imagedata SET imagedata.rank = (SELECT @i:=@i+1) WHERE imagedata.kategorieID = 1;
```

which I execute from top to bottom.

Question: Is ther a shorter way to do this?

---

thx for all the feedback..
but i have a differnet Idear now:
Somehow I have to "connect" the "kategorieID" with the "id(Primary key)" collumn
Therefore I need to store both information into the "rank" collumn in the format like:

cxxx

c=Category Number(0 to 4)
xxx = id (1 to ...n)..unique!

exampl.: output:

```
   rank
 +------+
 + 1001 +
 + 1002 +
 + 1003 +
 + ...  +
 + 1018 +
 + ...  +
 + 2001 +
 + 2002 +
 + 1019 +
 + 1020 +
```

so far I did it like:

```
UPDATE imagedata SET imagedata.rank = (SELECT CONCAT(kategorieID,"",LPAD(id,3,'0')) ) WHERE id=88;
```

once that "rank" is filled with data it gives me the abillity to swap 2 id's.

Therefore I have to:
1) get "rank" collumn of id_1 and id_2
2) get the substring ('xxx') of that string exampl: ("004" .. "012")
3) exchange substrings of id_1 "rank" and id_2 "rank"

```
SELECT @ix1:=SUBSTRING(rank, -3) FROM imagedata WHERE id=88;
SELECT @ix2:=SUBSTRING(rank, -3) FROM imagedata WHERE id=83;
```

..I know how to get it but dont know how to exchange it?

Comment: Can I back up a step and ask why you need to do this?

Comment: The second query can probably be omitted.

Comment: @TimWolla, I thought so too, but then realized he basically wants to set all `rank`s to 0 EXCEPT those with a `kategorieID` of 1, which should be incremented.

Comment: @Don Be sure to execute the whole in a transaction to avoid inconsistencies.

Comment: The website link in your user profile points to a website/linkfarm operated by a domain grabber. I guess it would be good to remove it from your profile since it's a) not your site (anymore), and b) useless for pretty much anyone.

Comment: Also, please note that SQL is by definition _unordered_ - there is no inherent 'top' or 'bottom'.  If you don't include an `ORDER BY` clause, rows are accessed (and updated) in what amounts to a **random** order; although this usually ends up being the order in an index, you have no garuantee which (if any) index this will actually be.

Comment: what i try to accomplish is to swap two rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify the second query to only update rows that WON'T be updated in the third, like so:

```
SELECT @i:=0;
UPDATE imagedata SET imagedata.rank = 0 WHERE imagedata.kategorieID <> 1;
UPDATE imagedata SET imagedata.rank = (SELECT @i:=@i+1) WHERE imagedata.kategorieID = 1;
```

**EDIT:** Per Lamak's comment, if the `kategorieID` could be `NULL` you'll want to do this instead:

```
SELECT @i:=0;
UPDATE imagedata SET imagedata.rank = 0 WHERE imagedata.kategorieID <> 1 OR imagedata.kategorieID IS NULL;
UPDATE imagedata SET imagedata.rank = (SELECT @i:=@i+1) WHERE imagedata.kategorieID = 1;
```

Also, it's possible that this solution may be slower than yours, especially if there isn't an index on `kategorieID`.  I say this because even though you are updating less rows, it now has to filter on that `WHERE` first.  Perhaps you should test the performance of this first to see if it is truly faster.

Comment: That maybe ok, but that way you are ommiting the rows that have a `NULL` kategorieId

Comment: the last line "UPDATE imagedata SET imagedata.rank = (SELECT @i:=@i+1) WHERE imagedata.kategorieID = 1;"..must somehow sort after my Primary Key?? How can I avoid that?